# R rsm contour for lm

Tags: r

i am pretty new in statistics and using R. I created a lm Object for a factorial Design with 3 factors. Now i want to plot the response contour. I have found the rsm package, but i was not able to build an equivalent rsm model, since coded.data object handles all variables as continuous numeric. 
However, the contour function takes a lm object. So i tried just to use my origin lm model. But i got the Error: in order(newdata[[v[1]]], newdata[[v[2]]]) : 
  argument 1 is not a vector

```
library(readr)
library(rsm)    

paraTuning <- read_csv("ParaTuning 2018.08.13.csv")

paraTuning$Velotype = as.factor(paraTuning$Velotype)
paraTuning$block = as.factor(paraTuning$block)

#paraTuning$AssignmentMutationProb = to_factor(paraTuning$AssignmentMutationProb)
#paraTuning$SwapRemoveProb = to_factor(paraTuning$SwapRemoveProb)

paraTuning$`Relative gap` = log(paraTuning$`Relative gap`+0.1)

model = lm(`Relative gap`~block+SwapRemoveProb*AssignmentMutationProb*Velotype ,data=paraTuning)
summary(model)

contour(model,x2~x1,image=TRUE) # crash!!! require rsm object!
# of course no problem at all
CR <- coded.data(paraTuning,x1~(SwapRemoveProb-0.5)/0.5,x2~(AssignmentMutationProb-0.5)/0.5,block = list("Velotype","block"))
CR.rsm1<-rsm(`Relative gap`~block+SO(x1,x2),data=CR,subset=(Velotype=="2"))
contour(CR.rsm1,x2~x1,image=TRUE)
```

How can I fix the error or set up an equivalent rsm model?
Furthermore, is there any difference in using as.factor and to_factor?
Here are the first 5 lines of the file.

```
ID,block,Iterations,Recombinations,TimeElapsed,SwapRemoveProb,AssignmentMutationProb,Velotype,Einstellung,Relative gap,Fitness
1,1,2000,2093010,6.59118922,0,0,1,1,0.364276443,769.5883417
2,1,2000,2079007,6.623102825,0,0,1,1,0.364276443,769.5883417
3,1,2000,2063005,6.73869278,0,0,1,1,0.364276443,769.5883417
4,1,2000,2079004,6.939622569,0,0,1,1,0.364276443,769.5883417
5,1,2000,2074003,7.133251938,0,0,1,1,0.364276443,769.5883417
```

**Edit:**
summary(model) output - block and Velotype are factors + second order x1^2 + x2^2

```
Call:
lm(formula = `Relative gap` ~ block + SwapRemoveProb * AssignmentMutationProb * 
    Velotype + I(SwapRemoveProb^2) + I(AssignmentMutationProb^2), 
    data = paraTuning)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.13650 -0.19154 -0.00969  0.20454  0.91650 

Coefficients:
                                                 Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                     -0.624705   0.007068  -88.390  < 2e-16 ***
block2                                           0.118510   0.003497   33.893  < 2e-16 ***
block3                                           0.014220   0.003497    4.067 4.77e-05 ***
block4                                           0.005503   0.003497    1.574 0.115553    
block5                                          -0.046342   0.003497  -13.254  < 2e-16 ***
block6                                          -0.047255   0.003497  -13.515  < 2e-16 ***
block7                                          -0.043856   0.003497  -12.543  < 2e-16 ***
block8                                          -0.220289   0.003497  -63.002  < 2e-16 ***
block9                                           0.415866   0.003497  118.936  < 2e-16 ***
block10                                         -0.020386   0.003497   -5.830 5.55e-09 ***
SwapRemoveProb                                  -2.369575   0.013292 -178.272  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb                          -0.420653   0.013292  -31.647  < 2e-16 ***
Velotype2                                       -1.048002   0.009194 -113.985  < 2e-16 ***
Velotype3                                       -0.798961   0.009194  -86.899  < 2e-16 ***
Velotype4                                       -0.953966   0.009194 -103.758  < 2e-16 ***
Velotype5                                       -0.577996   0.009194  -62.865  < 2e-16 ***
Velotype6                                       -0.440016   0.009194  -47.858  < 2e-16 ***
Velotype7                                       -0.470197   0.009194  -51.141  < 2e-16 ***
I(SwapRemoveProb^2)                              2.436897   0.007836  310.989  < 2e-16 ***
I(AssignmentMutationProb^2)                      0.346536   0.007836   44.224  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb:AssignmentMutationProb            0.097024   0.017731    5.472 4.46e-08 ***
SwapRemoveProb:Velotype2                         0.334921   0.015184   22.058  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb:Velotype3                        -0.025541   0.015184   -1.682 0.092546 .  
SwapRemoveProb:Velotype4                         0.008144   0.015184    0.536 0.591715    
SwapRemoveProb:Velotype5                        -0.554558   0.015184  -36.523  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb:Velotype6                        -0.659950   0.015184  -43.464  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb:Velotype7                        -0.657391   0.015184  -43.296  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb:Velotype2                 0.063261   0.015184    4.166 3.10e-05 ***
AssignmentMutationProb:Velotype3                 0.121300   0.015184    7.989 1.37e-15 ***
AssignmentMutationProb:Velotype4                 0.027265   0.015184    1.796 0.072551 .  
AssignmentMutationProb:Velotype5                -0.005575   0.015184   -0.367 0.713478    
AssignmentMutationProb:Velotype6                -0.099939   0.015184   -6.582 4.66e-11 ***
AssignmentMutationProb:Velotype7                -0.021671   0.015184   -1.427 0.153517    
SwapRemoveProb:AssignmentMutationProb:Velotype2  0.083709   0.025075    3.338 0.000843 ***
SwapRemoveProb:AssignmentMutationProb:Velotype3 -0.045736   0.025075   -1.824 0.068160 .  
SwapRemoveProb:AssignmentMutationProb:Velotype4 -0.085764   0.025075   -3.420 0.000626 ***
SwapRemoveProb:AssignmentMutationProb:Velotype5 -0.026143   0.025075   -1.043 0.297135    
SwapRemoveProb:AssignmentMutationProb:Velotype6 -0.010413   0.025075   -0.415 0.677936    
SwapRemoveProb:AssignmentMutationProb:Velotype7 -0.064842   0.025075   -2.586 0.009713 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2775 on 125961 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7154,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7153 
F-statistic:  8332 on 38 and 125961 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

summary(model) output - all categorial predictors

```
Call:
lm(formula = `Relative gap` ~ block + SwapRemoveProb * AssignmentMutationProb * 
    Velotype, data = paraTuning)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.93936 -0.15266  0.00982  0.15636  0.77895 

Coefficients:
                                                        Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                           -0.9484205  0.0093919 -100.983  < 2e-16 ***
block2                                                 0.1185101  0.0025998   45.584  < 2e-16 ***
block3                                                 0.0142200  0.0025998    5.470 4.52e-08 ***
block4                                                 0.0055026  0.0025998    2.117 0.034303 *  
block5                                                -0.0463420  0.0025998  -17.825  < 2e-16 ***
block6                                                -0.0472548  0.0025998  -18.176  < 2e-16 ***
block7                                                -0.0438562  0.0025998  -16.869  < 2e-16 ***
block8                                                -0.2202886  0.0025998  -84.732  < 2e-16 ***
block9                                                 0.4158655  0.0025998  159.958  < 2e-16 ***
block10                                               -0.0203856  0.0025998   -7.841 4.50e-15 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2                                     -0.0032583  0.0130511   -0.250 0.802850    
SwapRemoveProb0.4                                     -0.0005868  0.0130511   -0.045 0.964139    
SwapRemoveProb0.6                                      0.0012509  0.0130511    0.096 0.923645    
SwapRemoveProb0.8                                      0.0034551  0.0130511    0.265 0.791214    
SwapRemoveProb1                                        0.0054196  0.0130511    0.415 0.677954    
AssignmentMutationProb0.2                             -0.1731648  0.0130511  -13.268  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.4                             -0.1755351  0.0130511  -13.450  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.6                             -0.1788021  0.0130511  -13.700  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.8                             -0.1780580  0.0130511  -13.643  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb1                               -0.1767305  0.0130511  -13.541  < 2e-16 ***
Velotype2                                             -0.1740800  0.0130511  -13.338  < 2e-16 ***
Velotype3                                             -0.0406991  0.0130511   -3.118 0.001818 ** 
Velotype4                                             -0.8312534  0.0130511  -63.692  < 2e-16 ***
Velotype5                                             -0.0616283  0.0130511   -4.722 2.34e-06 ***
Velotype6                                             -0.0213636  0.0130511   -1.637 0.101649    
Velotype7                                             -0.0118484  0.0130511   -0.908 0.363959    
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.2            0.1663394  0.0184570    9.012  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.2            0.1691298  0.0184570    9.163  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.2            0.1701792  0.0184570    9.220  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.2            0.1728096  0.0184570    9.363  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.2              0.1731648  0.0184570    9.382  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.4            0.1663027  0.0184570    9.010  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.4            0.1714693  0.0184570    9.290  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.4            0.1716980  0.0184570    9.303  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.4            0.1746710  0.0184570    9.464  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.4              0.1754996  0.0184570    9.509  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.6            0.1669868  0.0184570    9.047  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.6            0.1696846  0.0184570    9.194  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.6            0.1743410  0.0184570    9.446  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.6            0.1788138  0.0184570    9.688  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.6              0.1783429  0.0184570    9.663  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.8            0.1626257  0.0184570    8.811  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.8            0.1711284  0.0184570    9.272  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.8            0.1741824  0.0184570    9.437  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.8            0.1762708  0.0184570    9.550  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.8              0.1776022  0.0184570    9.622  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb1              0.1635607  0.0184570    8.862  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb1              0.1703794  0.0184570    9.231  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb1              0.1748472  0.0184570    9.473  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb1              0.1736722  0.0184570    9.410  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb1                0.1765604  0.0184570    9.566  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:Velotype2                           -1.0099721  0.0184570  -54.720  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:Velotype2                           -1.0058022  0.0184570  -54.494  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:Velotype2                           -0.9228003  0.0184570  -49.997  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:Velotype2                           -0.7073653  0.0184570  -38.325  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:Velotype2                              0.0962646  0.0184570    5.216 1.84e-07 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:Velotype3                           -0.9410778  0.0184570  -50.988  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:Velotype3                           -1.1080066  0.0184570  -60.032  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:Velotype3                           -1.1162122  0.0184570  -60.476  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:Velotype3                           -0.9584047  0.0184570  -51.926  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:Velotype3                             -0.0369994  0.0184570   -2.005 0.045005 *  
SwapRemoveProb0.2:Velotype4                           -0.1656806  0.0184570   -8.977  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:Velotype4                           -0.1848871  0.0184570  -10.017  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:Velotype4                           -0.1621154  0.0184570   -8.783  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:Velotype4                           -0.1222473  0.0184570   -6.623 3.53e-11 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:Velotype4                              0.0406861  0.0184570    2.204 0.027500 *  
SwapRemoveProb0.2:Velotype5                           -0.9597984  0.0184570  -52.002  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:Velotype5                           -0.9776637  0.0184570  -52.970  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:Velotype5                           -0.9847754  0.0184570  -53.355  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:Velotype5                           -0.9706634  0.0184570  -52.591  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:Velotype5                             -0.7273719  0.0184570  -39.409  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:Velotype6                           -0.6466411  0.0184570  -35.035  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:Velotype6                           -0.8638435  0.0184570  -46.803  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:Velotype6                           -0.9312597  0.0184570  -50.456  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:Velotype6                           -0.9384262  0.0184570  -50.844  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:Velotype6                             -0.7124085  0.0184570  -38.598  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:Velotype7                           -0.7451392  0.0184570  -40.372  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:Velotype7                           -0.9501609  0.0184570  -51.480  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:Velotype7                           -1.0128507  0.0184570  -54.876  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:Velotype7                           -1.0359143  0.0184570  -56.126  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:Velotype7                             -0.7251910  0.0184570  -39.291  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype2                   -0.4611114  0.0184570  -24.983  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype2                   -0.4427387  0.0184570  -23.988  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype2                   -0.4376682  0.0184570  -23.713  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype2                   -0.4189664  0.0184570  -22.700  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype2                     -0.3988381  0.0184570  -21.609  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype3                   -0.0293864  0.0184570   -1.592 0.111352    
AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype3                   -0.0045930  0.0184570   -0.249 0.803477    
AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype3                    0.0266054  0.0184570    1.441 0.149452    
AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype3                    0.0574726  0.0184570    3.114 0.001847 ** 
AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype3                      0.0811005  0.0184570    4.394 1.11e-05 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype4                    0.0773231  0.0184570    4.189 2.80e-05 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype4                    0.0866955  0.0184570    4.697 2.64e-06 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype4                    0.1104680  0.0184570    5.985 2.17e-09 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype4                    0.1180725  0.0184570    6.397 1.59e-10 ***
AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype4                      0.1383054  0.0184570    7.493 6.76e-14 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype5                    0.0395880  0.0184570    2.145 0.031965 *  
AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype5                    0.0508957  0.0184570    2.758 0.005825 ** 
AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype5                    0.0782647  0.0184570    4.240 2.23e-05 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype5                    0.0925803  0.0184570    5.016 5.28e-07 ***
AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype5                      0.1099097  0.0184570    5.955 2.61e-09 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype6                    0.1758441  0.0184570    9.527  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype6                    0.1805351  0.0184570    9.781  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype6                    0.1898814  0.0184570   10.288  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype6                    0.1928818  0.0184570   10.450  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype6                      0.1920427  0.0184570   10.405  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype7                    0.0822994  0.0184570    4.459 8.24e-06 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype7                    0.1089173  0.0184570    5.901 3.62e-09 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype7                    0.1273503  0.0184570    6.900 5.23e-12 ***
AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype7                    0.1335722  0.0184570    7.237 4.62e-13 ***
AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype7                      0.1490236  0.0184570    8.074 6.86e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype2  0.3717529  0.0261021   14.242  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype2  0.3673115  0.0261021   14.072  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype2  0.3252155  0.0261021   12.459  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype2  0.3038559  0.0261021   11.641  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype2    0.4110531  0.0261021   15.748  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype2  0.4102527  0.0261021   15.717  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype2  0.3722260  0.0261021   14.260  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype2  0.3372986  0.0261021   12.922  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype2  0.3044782  0.0261021   11.665  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype2    0.3673912  0.0261021   14.075  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype2  0.4975366  0.0261021   19.061  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype2  0.4488679  0.0261021   17.197  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype2  0.3994692  0.0261021   15.304  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype2  0.3697794  0.0261021   14.167  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype2    0.3400001  0.0261021   13.026  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype2  0.5859716  0.0261021   22.449  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype2  0.5321156  0.0261021   20.386  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype2  0.4854390  0.0261021   18.598  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype2  0.4508490  0.0261021   17.272  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype2    0.3307505  0.0261021   12.671  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype2    0.6627505  0.0261021   25.391  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype2    0.6095482  0.0261021   23.352  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype2    0.5564854  0.0261021   21.320  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype2    0.5477225  0.0261021   20.984  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype2      0.3253266  0.0261021   12.464  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype3 -0.1893166  0.0261021   -7.253 4.10e-13 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype3 -0.0872452  0.0261021   -3.342 0.000831 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype3 -0.0643415  0.0261021   -2.465 0.013703 *  
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype3 -0.0890999  0.0261021   -3.414 0.000642 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype3   -0.0268402  0.0261021   -1.028 0.303822    
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype3 -0.1840808  0.0261021   -7.052 1.77e-12 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype3 -0.0801815  0.0261021   -3.072 0.002128 ** 
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype3 -0.0645971  0.0261021   -2.475 0.013333 *  
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype3 -0.0855890  0.0261021   -3.279 0.001042 ** 
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype3   -0.0820897  0.0261021   -3.145 0.001662 ** 
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype3 -0.1608866  0.0261021   -6.164 7.13e-10 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype3 -0.0577995  0.0261021   -2.214 0.026806 *  
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype3 -0.0382778  0.0261021   -1.466 0.142525    
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype3 -0.0516851  0.0261021   -1.980 0.047693 *  
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype3   -0.1242133  0.0261021   -4.759 1.95e-06 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype3 -0.1572086  0.0261021   -6.023 1.72e-09 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype3 -0.0243968  0.0261021   -0.935 0.349963    
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype3  0.0020628  0.0261021    0.079 0.937010    
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype3  0.0121941  0.0261021    0.467 0.640379    
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype3   -0.1461374  0.0261021   -5.599 2.16e-08 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype3   -0.1154923  0.0261021   -4.425 9.67e-06 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype3    0.0237890  0.0261021    0.911 0.362097    
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype3    0.0676186  0.0261021    2.591 0.009584 ** 
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype3    0.0747663  0.0261021    2.864 0.004179 ** 
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype3     -0.1593367  0.0261021   -6.104 1.04e-09 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype4 -0.1391419  0.0261021   -5.331 9.80e-08 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype4 -0.1270258  0.0261021   -4.866 1.14e-06 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype4 -0.1480909  0.0261021   -5.674 1.40e-08 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype4 -0.1585985  0.0261021   -6.076 1.24e-09 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype4   -0.1066675  0.0261021   -4.087 4.38e-05 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype4 -0.1436733  0.0261021   -5.504 3.71e-08 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype4 -0.1532051  0.0261021   -5.869 4.38e-09 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype4 -0.1567855  0.0261021   -6.007 1.90e-09 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype4 -0.1779429  0.0261021   -6.817 9.33e-12 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype4   -0.1082808  0.0261021   -4.148 3.35e-05 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype4 -0.1631099  0.0261021   -6.249 4.15e-10 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype4 -0.1622843  0.0261021   -6.217 5.07e-10 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype4 -0.1958725  0.0261021   -7.504 6.23e-14 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype4 -0.1986317  0.0261021   -7.610 2.76e-14 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype4   -0.1427858  0.0261021   -5.470 4.50e-08 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype4 -0.1820295  0.0261021   -6.974 3.10e-12 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype4 -0.1819334  0.0261021   -6.970 3.18e-12 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype4 -0.2041128  0.0261021   -7.820 5.33e-15 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype4 -0.2372701  0.0261021   -9.090  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.8:Velotype4   -0.1206579  0.0261021   -4.623 3.79e-06 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype4   -0.1994628  0.0261021   -7.642 2.16e-14 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype4   -0.2082177  0.0261021   -7.977 1.51e-15 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype4   -0.2147746  0.0261021   -8.228  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype4   -0.2113466  0.0261021   -8.097 5.69e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb1:Velotype4     -0.1299945  0.0261021   -4.980 6.36e-07 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype5 -0.1220259  0.0261021   -4.675 2.94e-06 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype5 -0.0938504  0.0261021   -3.596 0.000324 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype5 -0.0887194  0.0261021   -3.399 0.000677 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype5 -0.0579297  0.0261021   -2.219 0.026465 *  
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.2:Velotype5   -0.1015995  0.0261021   -3.892 9.93e-05 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype5 -0.1418732  0.0261021   -5.435 5.48e-08 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype5 -0.1203112  0.0261021   -4.609 4.05e-06 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype5 -0.1162080  0.0261021   -4.452 8.51e-06 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype5 -0.1158440  0.0261021   -4.438 9.08e-06 ***
SwapRemoveProb1:AssignmentMutationProb0.4:Velotype5   -0.1031790  0.0261021   -3.953 7.73e-05 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.2:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype5 -0.1793961  0.0261021   -6.873 6.32e-12 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.4:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype5 -0.1579134  0.0261021   -6.050 1.45e-09 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.6:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype5 -0.1504548  0.0261021   -5.764 8.23e-09 ***
SwapRemoveProb0.8:AssignmentMutationProb0.6:Velotype5 -0.1448539  0.0261021   -5.550 2.87e-08 ***
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 61 rows ]
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2064 on 125739 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8429,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8426 
F-statistic:  2595 on 260 and 125739 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

summary(model) output - all numeric predictors

```
lm(formula = `Relative gap` ~ block + SwapRemoveProb * AssignmentMutationProb * 
    Velotype + I(SwapRemoveProb^2) + I(AssignmentMutationProb^2), 
    data = paraTuning)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.13073 -0.29937 -0.04838  0.25899  1.39180 

Coefficients:
                                                 Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                    -1.2428216  0.0085173 -145.917  < 2e-16 ***
block                                           0.0034938  0.0003941    8.866  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb                                 -1.9500666  0.0173564 -112.354  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb                         -0.3345203  0.0173564  -19.274  < 2e-16 ***
Velotype                                        0.0009410  0.0017787    0.529   0.5968    
I(SwapRemoveProb^2)                             2.4368967  0.0113439  214.820  < 2e-16 ***
I(AssignmentMutationProb^2)                     0.3465360  0.0113439   30.548  < 2e-16 ***
SwapRemoveProb:AssignmentMutationProb           0.1275940  0.0216937    5.882 4.07e-09 ***
SwapRemoveProb:Velotype                        -0.1603905  0.0029373  -54.604  < 2e-16 ***
AssignmentMutationProb:Velotype                -0.0185103  0.0029373   -6.302 2.95e-10 ***
SwapRemoveProb:AssignmentMutationProb:Velotype -0.0129706  0.0048509   -2.674   0.0075 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4018 on 125989 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4034,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4033 
F-statistic:  8518 on 10 and 125989 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The function reports the same error messages for all model variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in not using the actual variable names in the call to `contour()`.

```
contour(model, SwapRemoveProb ~ AssignmentMutationProb, image = TRUE)
```

works correctly. But

```
contour(model, x2 ~ x1, image = TRUE)
```

produces the error message:

```
Error in order(newdata[[v[1]]], newdata[[v[2]]]) : 
  argument 1 is not a vector
```